# Android - Dagger injection inside the method

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2, dagger

In my application am using dagger, i would like to inject the class inside the method, but it shows compile time error

```
fun someMethod(){
  @Inject
  val testClass : TestClass
 }
```

It shows me error like

```
This annotation is not applicable to local variable
```

Any help how to handle this ?

Comment: No, you can't simply inject local variable due to it's scope is limited to method level. You'll need to declare that variable at Class level *(Global level)*.

Comment: any other option to declare like this ? @JeelVankhede

Comment: You can declare it at class level *(outside you method)* like this : 
`@JvmField
 @Inject
 var testClass : TestClass? = null`

Answer (score 1):

Inject element should be in the  activity or fragment

```
@Inject
lateint var testClass : TestClass  //global declaration


fun someMethod(){
testClass.dosomething()
}
```

Comment: What if we need instance of this testClass on the moment of calling someMethod()? It could be not the same than on class initialization